# How to animate a sequence of images using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, swiftui

How can I animate a sequence of images (say Frame-1.png all the to Frame-6) using the SwiftUI framework?

I've tried creating an array of "images". Then I assigned the UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 1.0) method to a variable called "animatedImage"
finally I tried Image(uiImage: animatedImage) in "body" of "ContentView.swift"

```swift
var images: [UIImage]! = [UIImage(named: "Sequence/frame-1")!,
                          UIImage(named: "Sequence/frame-2")!,
                          UIImage(named: "Sequence/frame-3")!,
                          UIImage(named: "Sequence/frame-4")!,
                          UIImage(named: "Sequence/frame-5")!,
                          UIImage(named: "Sequence/frame-6")!
]

let animatedImage : UIImage! = UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 1.0)

//////Then in the ContentView.swift I've tried this code:

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {

        Image(uiImage: animatedImage)

    }
}
```

when I run the program it just shows the firs frame, but I expected an animation of the frames

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accepted answer works very well, with the unfortunate issues mentioned by bhagyash ingale which makes it very hard to use. It would be useful if the specific methods of `Image` could be reused via protocols or something. I have a very poor and maybe huge cannon for a fly solution for this, maybe it'll be easier in time but for now...

```
class LoadingTimer {

    let publisher = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .default)
    private var timerCancellable: Cancellable?

    func start() {
        self.timerCancellable = publisher.connect()
    }

    func cancel() {
        self.timerCancellable?.cancel()
    }
}
```

```
struct LoadingView: View {

    @State private var index = 0

    private let images = (0...7).map { UIImage(named: "Image-\($0).jpg")! }
    private var timer = LoadingTimer()

    var body: some View {

        return Image(uiImage: images[index])
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            .onReceive(
                timer.publisher,
                perform: { _ in
                    self.index = self.index + 1
                    if self.index >= 7 { self.index = 0 }
                }
            )
            .onAppear { self.timer.start() }
            .onDisappear { self.timer.cancel() }
    }
}
```

I don't like this but it gets the job done and relies on a `Image`.

Comment: **Nice answer**, loved two things in your answer: 1- use of **.map** method, 2- use of **Publisher** from **Combine** framework. btw ,I didn't get it why did you write `private var image = Image(uiImage: images[index])` (It's not needed I guess)

Comment: Ah you’re right. It’s from the previous tries and forgot to remove it. I’ll update the answer.

Comment: This seems promising. I am getting the error `Cannot find type 'Cancellable' in scope` - anything library that needs to be loaded for this?

Comment: You need to import combine.

Answer (score 8):

Version without Combine

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimatingImage: View {
    let images: [Image]

    @ObservedObject private var counter = Counter(interval: 0.05)
        
    var body: some View {
        images[counter.value % images.count]
    }
}

private class Counter: ObservableObject {
    private var timer: Timer?

    @Published var value: Int = 0
    
    init(interval: Double) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { _ in self.value += 1 }
    }
}
```

You can use it

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    private let images = (1...20).map { String(format: "i_%02d", $0) }.map { Image($0) }
    
    var body: some View {
        AnimatingImage(images: images)
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `ObservableObject` part of Combine?

Comment: In this case `ObservableObject` is a part of `SwiftUI`, because `@ObservedObject` should be `ObservableObject`.

Comment: `@ObservedObject` should be `@StateObject`. In the case of `@ObservedObject`, whenever the counter value updates, the view is redrawn and reinitializes the `Counter` object making the `value` 0 again so the image never animates and stays on the first frame.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a pure SwftUI animation from image array :
It is using an animatable modifier that handle the images to be displayed in place of a view (here an button with an image). When you tap a button its image animates. If you tap again image stop animating and default button image
is displayed:

```
//
//  ImageArrayAnimationView
//
//  Created by Pitt Xav
//
import SwiftUI

struct ImageArrayAnimationView: View {
    // List of images
    private let images: [Image] = [
        Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.up"),
        Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down"),
        Image(systemName: "cloud"),
        Image(systemName: "cloud.drizzle"),
        Image(systemName: "cloud.rain"),
        Image(systemName: "cloud.heavyrain")
    ]
    // Images and percent variable use for animating rain down
    private let imagesOrderDown = [2, 4, 5]
    @State var percentDown: Float = 0

    // Images and percent variable use for animating rain up
    @State var percentUp: Float = 0
    private let imagesOrderUp = [5, 3, 2]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                // tapping a button set percent to :
                // 0 = no animation (Animation.default)
                // 100 = animation with images
                Button {percentDown = percentDown < 50 ? 100 : 0} label: {
                    Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.down")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .top)
                    .imageArrayAnimation(images: images, imagesOrder: imagesOrderDown, percent: percentDown)
                    .animation(percentDown <= 0 ? Animation.default : .linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: percentDown)
                    .border(.foreground, width: 2)
                    Spacer()
                }

                Button {percentUp = percentUp < 50 ? 100 : 0} label: {
                    Image(systemName: "icloud.and.arrow.up")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .top)
                    .imageArrayAnimation(images: images, imagesOrder: imagesOrderUp, percent: percentUp)
                    .animation(percentUp <= 0 ? Animation.default : .linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: percentUp)
                    .border(.foreground, width: 2)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}

struct ImageAnimation: AnimatableModifier {
    // Animation through th percent property
    // percent is converted into a position in an index array
    // this index value enable to choose whch image in the array
    // to display
    var animatableData: Float {
        get {
            percent
        }
        set {
            percent = newValue
        }
    }
    var images: [Image]
    var imgesOrder: [Int]
    var percent: Float
    var currentImageIndex: Int {
        if percent > 0 {
            let index = Int((percent / 100) *  Float(imgesOrder.count))
            print("% \(percent) \(index)")
            return imgesOrder[min(index, imgesOrder.count-1)]
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            // for the animation to work content and image
            // needs to always be there
            // opacity enable to choose what to actually display
            content
                .opacity(percent == 0 ? 1 : 0)
            images[currentImageIndex]
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .opacity(percent == 0 ? 0 : 1)
            
        }
    }
}

// extension to have mnamed modifier
extension View {
    func imageArrayAnimation(images: [Image], imagesOrder: [Int], percent: Float) -> some View {
        self.modifier(ImageAnimation(images: images, imgesOrder: imagesOrder, percent: percent))
    }
}

struct ImageArrayAnimationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ImageArrayAnimationView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have three image assets that I want to animate sequentially and repeatedly named: thinking1, thinking2 and thinking3. Based on nightwill's answer this works in iOS 14.4

```
// images[counter.value % images.count] mod ensures counter never exceeds images.count

import SwiftUI

struct ThinkingView: View {
    
    let images: [Image] = (1...3).map { String(format: "thinking%01d", $0) }.map { Image($0) }
    
    @ObservedObject private var counter = Counter(interval: 0.1)
    
    var body: some View {
        images[counter.value % images.count]
    }
}

private class Counter: ObservableObject {
    private var timer: Timer?

    @Published var value: Int = 0
    
    init(interval: Double) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true) { _ in self.value += 1 }
    }
}

struct ThinkingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ThinkingView()
    }
}
```